# Object not set to an instance of an object error after reading in over 1000 lines

Tags: vb.net, csv

I am using this loop in VB.net to read in CSV files:

```
Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(BrowseFile.Text)
    Reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    Reader.SetDelimiters(","c)
    Dim fileLineArray As String()
    While Not Reader.EndOfData
        'skip first line
        Reader.ReadLine()

        fileLineArray = Reader.ReadFields()

        csv_vh_calltype = Trim(fileLineArray(0))
        csv_vh_customer_cli = Trim(fileLineArray(1))
        csv_vh_telephone_number_called = Trim(fileLineArray(2))
    End While
End Using
```

It is reading in the CSV file but on one particular file it stops at line 1655 throwing an error saying:

```
Object is not set to an instance of an object
```

I have checked the file and the line it stops at is the same as the other lines.

The error is thrown on `Trim(fileLineArray(0))` and I cannot work out why it is doing this.

Comment: You're declaring `fileLineArray` within the loop. I think that `Reader.ReadFields()` is returning null on that particular loop.

Comment: You are not skipping just the first line, but every odd line in your file. Start moving the call to ReadLine outside the loop and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Reader.ReadLine inside the loop. This makes your code reach a point where the subsequent Reader.ReadFields works out of the End of Data. In this context the Reader.ReadFields return a Nothing and your following attempt to read a field triggers the infamous NullReferenceException

Your code actually is like this

```
While Not Reader.EndOfData

    ' reads line 1, 3, 5, 7 etc...
    Reader.ReadLine()

    ' reads line 2, 4, 6, 8 etc but don't check if EndOfData is true
    fileLineArray = Reader.ReadFields()
```

Instead you should write

```
Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(BrowseFile.Text)
    Reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    Reader.SetDelimiters(","c)
    Dim fileLineArray As String()

    'skip first line
    Reader.ReadLine()

    While Not Reader.EndOfData

        fileLineArray = Reader.ReadFields()

        csv_vh_calltype = Trim(fileLineArray(0))
        csv_vh_customer_cli = Trim(fileLineArray(1))
        csv_vh_telephone_number_called = Trim(fileLineArray(2))
    End While
End Using
```